# Why do I keep getting to an “InvalidPublicKey” error?

Tags: go, signature, verification

I am trying to validate a signature, but I run into the error "InvalidPublicKey"
When I debug into the library, it comes from the function Affine::is_valid_var() which suggests the group element not on the curve.

Here is the code that I execute. The values are the same as when I run similar code in golang, where the signature verifies successfully.

```
extern crate libsecp256k1;
use libsecp256k1::{Message, PublicKey, PublicKeyFormat, Signature, verify};
extern crate x509_parser;
use x509_parser::pem::parse_x509_pem;
extern crate spki;
use spki::SubjectPublicKeyInfo;

fn main() {
pub const PUBKEY_TEST: &str = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEQem4RK/YPgiT83UqNnIAx7GAFX3b
948NbKnilBKoD5t/4LSKDmP/X7qCrEIQ8TafiXB2r3mW9BPlX1mGZ0iYXw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
let (rem, pem) = parse_x509_pem(&PUBKEY_TEST.as_bytes()).unwrap();
assert!(rem.is_empty());
assert_eq!(pem.label, String::from("PUBLIC"));
let pub_key = SubjectPublicKeyInfo::try_from(pem.contents.as_slice()).unwrap();
assert_eq!(pub_key.subject_public_key.len(), 65);
assert_eq!(pub_key.subject_public_key[0], 4); // tag pubkey full
let pubkey = PublicKey::parse_slice(&pub_key.subject_public_key, Some(PublicKeyFormat::Full)).unwrap();
}
```

I have tried getting into GitHub, but no response. Also, I have been trying to look everywhere, and nothing.

Comment: It's not a secp256k1 key, it's a secp256r1 (aka NIST P-256 aka prime256v1) key.